# How to make input value never changed in Java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("enter numbers: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int nums[] = new int[9];
    int noChange[] = new int[9];
    for (int n = 0; n < 9; n++) {
        nums[n] = input.nextInt();
        n++;
    }
    noChange = nums;
    getNextPermutation(nums);
    while (hasNextPermutation(nums) == true) {
        getNexpermutation(nums);...
    }
    Reverse(nums);
    else {
        while (!Arrays.equals(nums, noChange)) {
            getNextPermutation(nums)
        }
    }
    public static void getNextPermutation(int nums[]) {
        int j = nums.length - 2;
        while (nums[j] > nums[j + 1]) {
            j--;
        }
        int k = nums.length - 1;
        while (nums[j] > nums[k]) {
            k--;
        }
        int temp = nums[j];
        nums[j] = nums[k];
        nums[k] = temp;
        int r = nums.length - 1;
        int s = j + 1;
        while (r > s) {
            int temp2 = nums[s];
            nums[s] = nums[r];
            nums[r] = temp2;
            s++;
            r--;
        }
    }
}
```

Some code that is not important to this question are omitted and I marked where the problem is. So I was trying to store input value into a new array, I was thinking that the value would not changed. However, when I test the code there, the result presented changed value to me. Such that I cannot compare "nums" and " nochange"...I am stuck on the store input into another place and never changed. What I am thinking is, when I want to use it, such as compare to changeable nums, I can grab it and do comparison. However, the input value does changed. I just wandering how to keep a input value separately and don't change?

Comment: please format your code, it´s pretty hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are *reference* types in Java.

In writing `noChange = nums` you are changing what `noChange` refers to: it now refers to *same* array as `nums`. (The previous array that `noChange` was referring to is now eligible for garbage collection!)

So you can change that array either by manipulating it through `nums` **or** by manipulating it through `noChange`. In your code you are changing the array through `nums`.

You probably want to *deep copy* the array. Do that using `noChange = nums.clone();`

Answer (score 0):

Example to copy an array:

```
int[] src  = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int[] dest = new int[5];

System.arraycopy( src, 0, dest, 0, src.length );
```

so you have to change this line:

```
noChange = nums;
```

to

```
System.arraycopy( nums, 0, noChange , 0, nums.length );
```

Comment: I don't pretend to be a Java expert. Is `arraycopy` preferred to `clone`?